# Authenticating with different Kerberos KDC in the same Java application

Tags: java, kerberos

Native Java support for Kerberos authentication uses system properties `java.security.krb5.kdc` and `java.security.krb5.realm` to specify which server exactly to ask to confirm user credentials. **Is there any good way to authenticate on different servers with the same application?**

E.g. I'd want to authenticate user `smith` on server `peons.company.com`, but user `johndoe` on `bigbosses.company.com`. I could try to use `System.setProperty()` to switch KDCs, but I have no idea if Java Kerberos implementation really supports that. Not to mention that it requires synchronization between threads and generally feel hacky.

*[Please don't tell me how I could solve this with different server configuration, I don't control those.]*

Comment: Kerberos does not authenticate *users*, it authenticates *principals* i.e. `user@REALM`; and different KDCs mean different realms. So your user `smith` has to actually authenticate as `smith@COMPANY.PEON` vs. `johndoe@COMPANY.VIP`

Comment: BTW, what kind of KDC implementation are you connecting to -- MIT, Microsoft Active Directory, something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read again the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/KerberosReq.html) -- you need to set these two properties ***if and only if*** you cannot point to a full Kerberos config file. And note that...

> if you set these properties, then *no cross-realm authentication* is
>   possible *unless* a krb5.conf file is also provided

So, the sane thing to do is to forget about these properties, and instead point to a detailed, custom config file with `java.security.krb5.conf`

That Kerberos config will contain, among other things,

- the list of realms with their specific KDCs *(the primary, and optionally the failover)*
- the mapping of servers to realms *(if you need to obtain Kerberos service tickets for your authenticated users on other servers)*
- the trust relationships between realms *(by default, a principal from `A.COMPANY.NET` trying to connect to a server from `B.COMPANY.NET` must hop to the root `COMPANY.NET` first, so you have to define that one in the list, too)*

The [MIT documentation for krb5.conf](http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/krb5-1.15/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html) is a bit dry but Google will get you some examples...